# How can I create a standalone Wicket executable?

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket

I have created a Wicket application for a final year programming project. I need to create an executable version of this project. How can I do this in such a way that the person trying to execute the file need not have Wicket, any of its libraries or Tomcat to execute the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Build WAR file (`mvn package` on `war` packaged project if using maven).
2. Put it in `/deploy` directory of fresh Tomcat.
3. Wrap Tomcat including WAR with [Tanuki Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp).
4. Give your customer ZIP file (or create GUI installer) and ask him to run a single script that install the service/deamon.

How were you working with your Wicket application so far?

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz just by starting Tomcat and typing in the URL into a web browser(localhost:8080/MyApp/app or something like that). The book I use suggests zipping up the context folder and making a .war extension-fo you just change the file extension(.zip) to .war? Thanks

Comment: The standard way (not only for Wicket web framework) is to package the application as WAR file (inside the WAR file you will find `wicket.jar` inside `/WEB-INF/lib`) and deploy it on servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz sorry, but this is the first time I'm doing this so bear with me-how does one package application as WAR inside wicket.jar.. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, it depends on your IDE/build tool, tips for: [Eclipse](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-make-war-file-in-eclipse.html), [Netbeans](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-45152.html), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) and [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/0.8/docs/userguide/war_plugin.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using eclipse-so create the WAR wherever I want. Then when I have the war what do I tell them to do? Just run it on Tomcat?

Comment: If your customer already has a Tomcat instance running, just copy the WAR file to Tomcat's `/deploy` directory.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz Do I have to take Wicket out of development mode and modify web.xml accordingly?. When my project supervisor runs the program on tomcat-what url would he type into the web browser(assume MyApp.java is the WebApplication class)

Comment: Wicket shouldn't run in `debug` mode on production. The application will be available under `localhost:8080/app-name`, where `app-name` is the name of your WAR file without extension. I strongly recommend you to take a look at some servlet and Tomcat tutorials.

Answer (score 5):

If you follow [these instructions](http://www.earldouglas.com/a-self-contained-runnable-web-application), you get a jar file which you can run like this:

```
java -jar selfcontained.jar
```

Comment: Wicket is a Web framework, so the application will need a servlet container. A runnable jar will not work.

Comment: If you actually read the link, you can see it creates a runnable Web application with embedded Jetty.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I missed the part where the Jetty container was included